# Was I too harsh in my comment on this post?

Tags: discussion, comments, code-of-conduct

Recently I stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55875967/sign-pdf-document-by-certificate-file-crt-p12-digital-signature). The content of the question was:

> need to sign a pdf file by certificate file (.cer/.p12) with python instruction : everyone have a private key and certificate generated with previous key . everyone sign a pdf file by a certificate file , included in the pdf file the traditional signature (signature drawing), and wen we want to know the signer .

I think this question is ridiculous for a few reasons:

- There's no question specific enough to answer.
- The user didn't include any attempt of them trying to solve their problem - it looks like they are asking others to do something for them.
- It seems like the user can't be bothered to use correct grammar.

Personally, I take offense to these kinds of posts. For starters, the user can't even spend a little time to include clarity in their post, it seems like they are demanding answers, and not even a "thank you in advance" or something like that! So I replied with my usual comment for these very-low-quality types of posts:

> Voted to close. Try a little harder when asking your question next time.

I didn't leave a downvote because that's against my beliefs - downvotes don't help anything, but explanations do. Do you think I was too harsh in this situation? Personally, I believe I was in the right (because of the low-effort reasons I presented above), but I'm willing to change my opinion and conduct if the consensus is that I was in the wrong.

---

On a somewhat related note, I'm starting to believe that I was in the right. The user replied to my comment saying:

> give me a solution and close the topic

This is a *demand*, almost an attack - and I don't really appreciate this remark. I replied once again with the following:

> Really? If you want a solution, you should possibly include what you have tried so far, or possibly make an attempt to use grammar or include clarity in your post? I can't exactly give you an answer when I *don't know what your question is.*

Please let me know your thoughts on this situation.

Comment: You're overreacting on the grammar aspect:  Non-native English speakers frequently have problems with it.

Comment: Yep, this one's on you. The tone of your initial comment was *dismissive*, and that's the best interpretation that can be put on it. Aside from considering whether is was "welcoming and fluffy" enough,  common polite courtesy would have resulted in a better comment.

Comment: As an aside - you haven't voted to close - the ability to do that comes at [3k reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions). You have flagged for closure, which is different (flags won't directly cause a question to be closed, but they will cause it to enter a review queue for closure where 3k users can cast close votes).

Comment: My only issue with the comment is how unhelpful they are. If the user is new to stack and not 100% sure of our rules, how does 'try harder' help him? If I go on every downvoted question and post 'Git Gud', does it help anyone improve? Or would I better not say anything?

Comment: "I didn't leave a downvote because that's against my beliefs - downvotes don't help anything" Well...votes aren't for the poster. They're not meant to help them. They're meant to help *everyone else* after the poster. If you're not downvoting for that reason, some additional familiarity with the site would help greatly.

Answer (score 37):

There's no reason to post that comment pretty much ever. Nobody needs to see an announcement of your voting to close (unless you're using a special off-topic reason). And the rest of your comment is pointless. Vapid statements like "try harder" accomplish nothing, even if someone were in a mood to improve. There is really no point in commenting unless you're talking about something *specific* which can be improved. General "do better" advice isn't helpful.

The correct response is to close vote, downvote (it's a crap question; there's no excuse for not doing it, and refraining from doing so for obvious bad questions like this is hurting the site), and move on. Do not engage.

Answer (score 7):

First off, I hope you don't get crazy downvoted, because just the fact that you came here to *ask* if you were too harsh, and demonstrate willingness to listen to other arguments, shows you care about the outcome. So kudos to you for that.

I would say that your initial comment was overly terse, and most importantly it did not contain any *constructive* criticism ... but it wasn't so harsh that I would flag it.  Your second comment was fine - a little frustration showing but honestly given the comment you were responding to it's pretty mild.  This user is clearly not the kind of user we want to be overly "welcoming" toward.

As in a few comments, you do need to take into account that non-English speakers sometimes have issues with grammar; however, one can usually tell the difference between someone who is trying but not quite succeeding and someone who isn't trying at all, and the question at hand seems very much like the latter (e.g. 'wen' is not a word.)  But it is something to keep in mind.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful explanation.

Comment: 'clearly not the kind of user we want to be welcoming towards'. Then you *walk away*. You don't respond. The CoC applies, even if the person you're speaking to is unreasonable. Two wrongs don't make a right.